Can't Install Iterm2 to Homebrew Using Standard User Account
Over the past year I stopped logging into my mac using an admin account and do all my day-to-day tasks with a standard user account.  I use homebrew, and initially installed it with my admin account.  Today when running 'brew upgrade' I was prompted to enter my sudo password.  Since I'm not in the admin group, I get the message "UserName is not in the sudoers file."  If I attempt to run 'brew upgrade' using my admin account, I get permission errors as the files are all owned by my standard user.
How do I resolve the situation?  I fixed for now by temporarily adding my standard user to the admin group to complete the upgrade, but that doesn't seem like the best long-term solution.
